# Manually call DbMigration.Up in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to be able to Up() method of a migration manually. Currently I'm trying to do that but calling that contains CreateTable method does not create the table. I suspect that connection is not properly set. And there are no properties to set it.

I also tried DbMigrator but it calls some internal EF migration methods.

So does anyone know how to set a connection to be used by DbMigration.Up method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Entity Framework is open source, so you could look at the source code to figure out exactly what they are doing to make the migrations happen. http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I could not find the solution. Looks like I'm trying to do what I'm not supposed to. Manage to solve the issue the other way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For complete manual control over migrations, you can use the following extension method:

```
public static void RunMigration(this DbContext context, DbMigration migration)
{            
    var prop = migration.GetType().GetProperty("Operations", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (prop != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations = prop.GetValue(migration) as IEnumerable<MigrationOperation>;
        var generator = new SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator();
        var statements = generator.Generate(operations, "2008");
        foreach (MigrationStatement item in statements)
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(item.Sql);
    }
}
```

Example:
Having a migration like this:

```
public class CreateIndexOnContactCodeMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        this.CreateIndex("Contacts", "Code");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        base.Down();
        this.DropIndex("Contacts", "Code");
    }
}
```

You could run it against your DbContext:

```
using (var dbCrm = new CrmDbContext(connectionString))
{
    var migration = new CreateIndexOnContactCodeMigration();
    migration.Up(); // or migration.Down();                
    dbCrm.RunMigration(migration);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I use the following code to explicitly be able to upgrade my database in the Application_Start event:

```
var config = new MyDatabaseMigrationsConfiguration();
var migrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator(new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(config), new MyCommonMigrationsLogger());
if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
{
  migrator.Update();
}
```

As far as i know this will use the default (named) connectionstring from my DatabaseContext to apply the pending changes.

- You can specify the TargetMigration in the migrator.Update() if you want to be explicit
- The MyCommonMigrationsLogger is just a simple Logging.Common implementation for the System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsLogger

Comment: I already tried this but it's not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to do the following in my initializer:  `Migrations.MigrationV103 migration = new Migrations.MigrationV103();
            migration.Up();`

Comment: Might not be what the OP was after, but that logging migrator line of code is awesome! Thank you for that code snippet. I can now log programatic migrations.